# Angular 6 CLI does not copy library's assets folder into dist folder

Tags: angular, libraries

How to use an external javascript file in angular library? Do we need to export that in public_api file? Added an external JS file in **asset** folder of a custom library. But it's not showing in Dist folder once it's build.

Comment: you can add a `js` folder in `asset`  folder and then add the  link to the scripts in `angular.json` file

Comment: If Joel's comment doesn't solve this, we'll need to see more to help - please include your angular.json file.

Comment: @JoelJoseph have to include in angular custom library that that created, not in the main project

Answer (score 0):

The "assets" property of angular.json can be configured to include custom files in angular-cli webpack build. So, configure "assets" property value as an array. For example:

"`assets": ["assets""],`

above configuration will copy asset folder into dist folder during the angular-cli webpack build.